# QPixmapやQMediaの画像やサウンドをpickleのように一つにまとめたい

Tags: python, pyqt

pyqtで表示する画像やサウンドを一つのファイルにまとめたいです。そこでそれらをpickle化しようと思い、次のようなコードを書いてみました。

```
import pickle
from PyQt5 import  QtWidgets,QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

img=QPixmap("画像.png")
img2=QPixmap("画像2.jpg")
list_image=[img,img2]
save_file=open("image_list.dat","wb")
pickle.dump(list_image,save_file)
save_file.close()

sound=QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("サウンド.wav"))
sound2=QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("サウンド2.wav"))
sound_list=[sound,sound2]
save_file2=open("sound_list.dat","wb")
pickle.dump(sound_list,save_file2)
save_file2.close()
```

しかし、これを実行すると

```
TypeError: can't pickle QMediaContent objects
```

や

```
TypeError: can't pickle QPixmap objects
```

と出力されます。QPixmapやQMediaはpickleに対応していないようです。これらの情報を一つのファイルにまとめるにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。pickle以外に対応しているものはあるのでしょうか。それともpickleでもうまくやれば十分カバーできるのでしょうか。

Comment: 回答をQtに合わせて更新してみました。ご一読いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**QPixmapオブジェクトを保存する方法について**
既に解決されたようですが、既存の[pyqt](/questions/tagged/pyqt)を使った方法を残しておきます。
[pyqt](/questions/tagged/pyqt)では、以下の方法によって、簡単にセーブとロードを行うことが出来ます。

```
file = QtCore.QFile(anyfile)
file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
out = QtCore.QDataStream()
image = QtGui.QPixmap()#An object you costomized.Please not use empty pixmap!
image = image.toImage()
out << image#C++でよくつかわれる記号
```

次に、取り出すときです。

```
file = QtCore.QFile(the same file)
file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
out = QtCore.QDataStream()
image = QtGui.QPixmap()#Please prepare empty pixmap object
image = image.toImage()
out >> image#C++でよくつかわれる記号 記号が逆になっています。
```

**waveファイルの保存について**
次に、[wave](/questions/tagged/wave)ファイルについてです。

質問者様は、`scipy.io.wave`で実装されたようですが、私は[python](/questions/tagged/python)標準の[wave](/questions/tagged/wave)で実装してみました。既にご存知かもと思いますが、[wave](/questions/tagged/wave)ファイルやほかの音声データファイルには、最初にたくさんの識別情報が含まれています。

```
import wave
wave_data = wave.open("any_file.wav","rb")
wave_read_data = wave_data.getfp().read()
wave_data_nchannels = wave_data.getnchannels()
wave_data_sampwidth = wave_data.getsampwidth()
wave_data_framerate = wave_data.getframerate()
wave_data_nframes = wave_data.getnframes()
wave_data_comptype = wave_data.getcomptype()
wave_data_compname = wave_data.getcompname()
wave_byte_data = QtCore.QByteArray(wave_read_data)

out.writeInt8(self.wave_data_nchannels)
out.writeInt8(self.wave_data_sampwidth)
out.writeInt64(self.wave_data_framerate)
out.writeInt64(self.wave_data_nframes)
out.writeQString(self.wave_data_comptype)
out.writeQString(self.wave_data_compname)
wave_data_byte = QtCore.QByteArray(self.wave_byte_data)
out << wave_data_byte
```

それらを、先ほどと同じ要領で、`QDataStream`に格納します。

これらを取り出す時には同じ要領でとりだします。

```
wave_data_nchannels = out.readInt8()
wave_data_sampwidth = out.readInt8()
wave_data_framerate = out.readInt64()
wave_data_nframes = out.readInt64()
wave_data_comptype = out.readQString()
wave_data_compname = out.readQString()
wave_byte_data = QtCore.QByteArray()
out >> wave_byte_data
```

この後、空のwaveファイルに入れ込みます。

```
p = wave.open("temporary.wav","wb")#一時的なwavファイルを作成する。     
p.setnchannels(wave_data_nchannels)   
p.setsampwidth(wave_data_sampwidth)
p.setframerate(wave_data_framerate)
p.setnframes(wave_data_nframes)
p.setcomptype(wave_data_comptype)
p.writeframes(wave_byte_data.data())
#音を発生させる。            
QtGui.QSound().play(p)
p.close()
```

このように、扱うモジュールによっては、`QDataStream`がとる型や順番も異なります。
`scipy.io.wave`ファイルは、少し制限があるような書き込みがされていましたので、
もしこちらをご検討いただければ嬉しいです。

自己解決された方法でも問題ないとは思いますが、このやり方でも、実体としての`wav`拡張子ファイルや、`png`,`JPEG`,`gif`,`svg`等の`image`ファイル自体がバイナリ化され、常にどこでも取り出し行う事ができるようになります。[qt](/questions/tagged/qt)をお使いであれば、この方法もご検討ください。`temporary file`は、音を再生するための、使いまわしのファイルです。

`QImage`や、`QByteArray`、`QColor`,`QPoint`,`QSize`,`QRect`等、`Qt`独自の型で定義されているオブジェクトであり、[python](/questions/tagged/python)の通常のデータに直すのが、面倒なデータは、そのままバイナリ化できるようになっているです。

逆に、`int`型や`str`型を、`<<`とか`>>`でデータに格納しようとすると、怒られますので,ちゃんとした`writeInt8~64`と`readInt8~64`メソッドを利用するようにしてください。

Comment: 非常に詳しい回答ありがとうございます！私にはまだまだ理解できないことも多いですが、頑張って勉強します。実際にpyqtで動かしてみたところ、out.writeQStringList(list_image)
のところでTypeError: index 0 has type 'QPixmap' but 'str' is expectedと出力されました。同様にQMediaの方でもout.writeQStringList(sound_list)の所で、TypeError: index 0 has type 'QUrl' but 'str' is expectedとエラーが出ました。

Comment: QPixmapですと、imageのファイル名はstr型で渡しますよね。"image.png"とか、soundファイルも同様で、"sound.wav"とか、str型だとできます。おそらくQPixmapそのものや、QUrlそのものを入れてしまっているからエラーが出るのだろうと思います。データを格納するときは、そのstr部分のみです。取り出す時は、再度QPixmapにその値を渡すようにして、アプリケーションを閉じる前のデータと同じデータを作り出すという考えです。

Comment: すいません。回答では、img1,img2がそのまま入れ込めるように書いてありますね。私の書き方がまずかったです。

Comment: 永続化は保存したい値を全て保存し、取り出す時は全て取り出すのが基本です。なので、何を保存し、保存すべきではないかという事は、大体感覚でもわかると思いますが、重要なことになります。そして再度取り出した値を、以前の同じ型、同じ変数へ当てはめて行って、前と同じような状態を作り出すという事になります。ユーザーからすると一瞬の作業で、そのまま格納できてそのまま呼び出せるみたいに思っていましたが、プログラマからすると、結構地道なプロセスだと思います。

Comment: 詳しいコメントありがとうございます。しかしこれだと文字列"画像.png"が保存されているだけで、画像の情報は何も保存されていないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @toma そうですね。なので必ず特定のフォルダにその画像が入るようにすることを前提としています。もしユーザーの利用状況によって新しい画像を取り出したり削除するようになる場合、その中に入っている画像という形で処理します。もし画像そのものを保存したければ、音楽や画像を数値(テキスト)変換する作業が必要になると思います。

Comment: PILとscipy.io.wavfileでそれぞれ画像とサウンドをpickle化できたのでそこから情報を戻したら出来ました。

Comment: 半年前の回答にさらに詳しい回答をいただいて感激しております！早速試してみたいと思います。